# Angularjs 1.6.4: pass controller variable into component tags

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie of angularjs, so might be i am doing something wrong. What i am trying to do, is to pass variable of another component controller into another component through tags. Below is the sample code.

post-view.template.html belongs to post-view component:

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{model.post.title}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{model.post.description}}</p>
</li>
</ul>

{{model.post.id}} <!-- getting value here -->
<rating-creator rating-type="1" parent-id="model.post.id"></rating-creator>
```

rating-creator.component.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module(__appName);

    function controller() {
        var model = this;

        model.$onInit = function () {
            //getting undefined here. Why?
            console.log("parent:"+model.parentId);
        };
    }

    module.component("ratingCreator", {
        templateUrl: "components/rating-creator/rating-creator.template.html",
        bindings: {
            ratingType: "<",
            parentId: "<"
        },
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: [controller]
    });

    }());
```

Comment: For the sake of debugging, try injecting `$scope` and log it to console

Comment: controller property value shouldn't be  an array

Comment: Use the [$onChanges Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) to see if the value becomes available after init.

Comment: yes, it does change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that `model.post.id` is not available when the component is being instantiated. Try using `ng-if` to only generate an instance of the component when `model.post.id` has a value other than undefined. It would look like this:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var model = this;

  // simulating model.post.id not being available on page load
  $timeout(function() {
    model.post = {
      id: 123
    };
  }, 1000);
});
```

**HTML**

`<rating-creator ng-if="model.post.id" rating-type="1" parent-id="model.post.id"></rating-creator>`

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sSe4mfnqdgAkHENdS4Z9?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. It uses a `$timeout` to simulate the `model.post.id` being populated async.

Hopefully that helps!